# Loading a hidden div into an AJAX jQuery UI tab (future DOM element)

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, dom, tabs, element

I have been trying to manipulate content that is loaded into jQuery UI tabs via AJAX.
As you can imagine, these elements are "future" DOM elements and aren't manipulated by normal $(".someClass")functions.

I've read using .live() for event handling is now deprecated using jQuery 1.7+ and is replaced by the new .on() method.

My issue is that the div I want to hide, when it loads in an AJAX tab, must be manipulated after the initial DOM load and is not bound to a click event at first.

My functions, which are currently wrapped in $() are below.

I think I have the syntax correct for links that use a click handler, but I'm not sure of the correct way to ".hide()" my "hiddenStory" div at load.

I also think that the functions themselves shouldn't be wrapped in an overall $()?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function(){
    // this .hiddenStory div below is what I want to hide on AJAX load
    // need syntax and/or new methods for writing this function
$(".hiddenStory").hide();

   // this is a function that allows me to toggle a "read more/read less" area
   // on the "hiddenStory" div
$(".showMoreOrLess").on('click', (function() {
if (this.className.indexOf('clicked') != -1 ) {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).prev().slideUp(500);
    $(this).html("Read More" + "<span class='moreUiIcon'></span>");
    }
    else {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).prev().slideDown(500);
    $(this).html("See Less" + "<span class='lessUiIcon'></span>");
    }       
}));
});

// prevents default link behavior 
// on BBQ history stated tab panes with    
// "showMoreOrLess" links
$('.showMoreOrLess').click(function (event) 
{ 
 event.preventDefault(); 
 // here you can also do all sort of things 
});
// /prevents default behavior on "showMoreOrLess" links
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you set the `display: none` via CSS and override it when you wanted to show the element's content? Another option, if you have to do it this way would be to add the `$(".hiddenStory").hide() in the callback from the AJAX load that is populating the element. For example:

```
$(".hiddenStory").load("http://myurl.com", function(){
        $(".hiddenStory").hide();
    }
);
```

If you aren't using the .load method, you should have some sort of call back to tie into (e.g. success if using $.ajax...)

Comment: Hey vansimke! Thanks! Your first option worked great in order to hide the "hiddenStory" div using "display: none" at the outset. I still need to fix the last part of the code that applies .preventDefault() to links in this area. This allows my tabs to  still work correctly while using jQuery BBQ to state the tabs' index in the URL. Would you mind showing me how to integrate this into one function or rewrite it using ".on()"?

Comment: // prevents default link behavior on BBQ history stated   
    //tab panes with "showMoreOrLess" links
 $(".showMoreOrLess").click(function (event) 
 { 
     event.preventDefault(); 
     //here you can also do all sort of things 
 });
     // /prevents default behavior on "showMoreOrLess" links

Comment: I can try. But, I'm not familiar with BBQ. Are the `$(.showMoreOrLess)` elements anchor tags?

Comment: Thanks again. It's no problem being unfamiliar with BBQ. I just need the $(.showMoreOrLess) anchor tags to prevent the default behavior. This keeps them from adding a "#" hash to the URL and let's BBQ continue to track the array of the tab indices. I didn't know if I could wrap that up in the same code blocks that currently use .on() in the first example above. I really appreciate you looking at this!